# Can stl functions that work on each member of a container accept external parameters?

Tags: c++, stl

I plan to execute an operation on each data of a std::vector array as the following codes show:

```
std::vector<int> abc;
abc.push_back(1);
abc.push_back(5);
abc.push_back(2);
std::sort(abc);
int min = abc[0];
int max = abc[2];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  abc[i] = (abc[i]-min)/(max-min);
```

The question I have now is that whehter I have more elegant way of performing

```
 for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
      abc[i] = (abc[i]-min)/(max-min)
```

with `for_each , trasnform` or other methods in stl. The difficulty I have with these functions lies in the fact that I do not know how to incorporate external parameters within them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example that uses `for_each` to update each element in `abc`:

```
std::for_each(abc.begin(),    // Start of range
              abc.end(),      // End of range
              [=](int &value) // The operation to apply
              {
                value=(value-min)/(max-min);
              });
```

Changing the sequence being iterated over by `for_each` is often frowned upon, despite the fact that `for_each` guarantees the order of traversal as well as how many invocations occur per element. However, to appease the naysayers, you may want to use `transform` instead which has no such guarantees (neither of the [order of traversal](http://www.drdobbs.com/effective-standard-c-library-foreach-vs/184403769) nor of the number of calls of the predicate other than via a [complexity guarantee](http://www.drdobbs.com/effective-standard-c-library-foreach-vs/184403769) {Note: the complexity has been modified to a guarantee of the number of calls in C++11, see 25.3.4.4}):

```
std::transform(abc.begin(),    // Start of source range
               abc.end(),      // End of source range
               abc.begin(),    // Start of destination range
               [=](int value)  // The operation to apply
               {
                 return (value-min)/(max-min);
               });
```

By the way, since you're doing integer division in your formula, you have to be very careful with the truncation of the result. You should probably check for a divide by zero, as well.

Comment: This is in the border line of undefined behavior... `std::for_each` explicitly allows calling non-constant functions through the dereferenced iterator. It is otherwise inside the group *non-modifying sequence operations*. I assume it will work, but the assignment in the lambda is not a member function and does change the sequence values...

Comment: @David, I beg to differ, the predicate used with `for_each` may modify the elements being iterated over. See for example [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Comment: Well, I would suggest that you check with the standard or one of the drafts. See for example [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), which is the closest draft to the C++11 standard. Also `std::transform` does offer those guarantees. The iterators are `InputIterators`, so the only way of transversing is moving forward (order guarantee), and the standard guarantes that exactly `last1-first1` applications of the operator are performed.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'm quite certain that "non-constant functions" is intended to include modifying operations on scalar objects.  If it's not, then the predicate of a call to an algorithm like `remove_if` *is* free to modify its argument if it is a scalar, because it uses the same language.  And it would be silly and backwards to think that.

Comment: @David, note #2 of 25.2.4 of the N3337 working draft explicitly allows for the calling of non-const member functions on `value` if mutable iterators are supplied. Assignment, logically, is such a function and is therefore permitted by the standard. I don't have a copy of the actual standard document, but I would imagine that the same wording is there. Perhaps someone with a copy of the standard document can confirm this.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: That is why I mentioned that this is borderline. Fundamental types like `int` don't have member functions. I believe this to be an issue with the wording in the standard, but as it is currently defined this is technically not allowed. Also, if you read the link you provided you will notice that at the time (2001) the standard forbid *any* modifications of the argument to the functor in `std::for_each`. The exception for *member functions* is from C++11. [You can use N3337 as if it was the standard, there are very little editorial changes]

Comment: @BenjaminLindley what you say makes sense, but then I cannot understand why `for_each` would be in *non-modifying sequence operations*. This seems inconsistent, unless I am missing something.

Comment: The normative text simply says that it "Applies `f` to the result of dereferencing every iterator" with nothing to suggest that you can't modify the values, and a note that specifically allows it to "apply nonconstant functions" if the iterators are mutable. This certainly implies to me that the values can be modified; but it doesn't explicitly say so, so there is room for pedantic quibbling.

Comment: @juanchopanza: "non-modifying" because the algorithm itself doesn't modify anything, and doesn't require mutable iterators.

Comment: @juanchopanza: The *non-modifying sequence operations* category is in reference to the algorithm logic itself.  In other words, you won't find any assignments against the dereferenced iterator inside the for_each code.

Answer (score 4):

With C++11 you could use a lambda that captures the needed variables:

```
std::transform(std::begin(abc), std::end(abc),
               std::begin(abc),
               [=](int x) { return (x-min)/(max-min); });
```

This is equivalent to your loop, although you might want to verify whether the logic was correct in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

This is easily achieved using `std::transform` and a suitable functor. Here, a lambda is used for brevity:

```
std::transform(std::begin(abc), 
               std::end(abc),
               std::begin(abc), 
               [&](int i) { return (i-min)/(max-min); });
```

It isn't clear whether this is an improvement. I would just write a plain range-based loop:

```
for(int& i : abc)
  i = (i-min)/(max-min);
```

Comment: @jrok: Juancho edited the answer, he initially was calling `std::for_each` with a lambda that took the argument by reference and modified it internally. I removed the comment as he has fixed the code.